# How to create a re-usable routerLink directive in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a common route throughout my application, it is referenced like so:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Project', {id: project.id, title: project.urlTitle}]" href="#">
  {{project.title}}
</a>
```

How can I make this logic re-usable using a directive or similar?

I.E Ideally I'd like to do something like:

```
<a [project-link]="project"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a component that contains the `routerLink`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems a bit overkill to create a component for that. I was hoping for a more minimalistic solution. But sounds like it isn't really possible...

Comment: No idea why you think this is overkill. That's exactly what a component is for, to create reusable functionality containing HTML (without HTML it would be a directive instead).

Comment: How would u wrap that component around some HTML elements?

Comment: @Halfacht I don't understand your question or what the problem is.

Comment: <app-project-router-link><p>How would this be dynamically without using Input(), because other components might be here</p><app-random-component><app-random-component></app-project-router-link>